# GameMaker 2: Cannot use function/script name for a variable, using "_dir"

Tags: variables, compiler-errors, gml, game-maker-studio-2

after going through the Space Mods - GML - Enemy Factions (2/3) - GameMaker Studio 2 tutorial on YouTube by Gamemaker.

I've came into some trouble with testing the game.

**My compile error goes like this:**
Script:create_bullet at line 6; cannot use function/script name for a variable, using "_dir"

The script in question:

```
/// @description create_bullet
/// @arg direction
/// @arg speed
/// @arg faction
function create_bullet(_dir,_spd,_fac,_creator){
var _dir = argument[0];
var _spd = argument[1];
var _fac = argument[2];
var _creator = self;

audio_play_sound(snd_zap, 1, false);
var inst = instance_create_layer(x,y, "Instances", obj_bullet);

with(inst){
    direction = _dir();
    speed = _spd;
    faction = _fac;
    creator = _creator;
    
    if(faction == factions.ally) image_blend = c_aqua;
    else if(faction == factions.enemy) image_blend = c_red;
}
}
```

I've checked the comments to see if anyone else has had a similar problem and I can't find the solution myself. Will anyone be able to help and explain. I'm quite new to coding and just taking it step by step.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer in another forum.

My mistake seems to have been placing brackets after `_dir;`:

```
   with(inst){
    direction = _dir(); <=
    speed = _spd;
    faction = _fac;
    creator = _creator;
```

After removing that and taking out the var before:

```
_dir = argument[0];
_spd = argument[1];
_fac = argument[2];
    
_creator = self;
```

It seems to work fine now.

Comment: Additionally, if you are using named arguments, you don't need `var _dir = argument[0];`